# What does "TetGenTetrahedralize: Tetrahedralize returned an error, 2. mean? Also error number 1,2,3...?

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method, mesh, opencascade, tetgenlink

```
regioncalc5 = ToElementMesh[regioncalc4, MeshRefinementFunction -> ff]
```

> > TetGenTetrahedralize: Tetrahedralize returned an error, 2.

Comment: Please provide the rest of your code, so that readers can reproduce the error and corresponding message.

Answer (score 6):

The TetGen manual at http://wias-berlin.de/software/tetgen/1.5/doc/manual/manual.pdf states for error code 2 (see appendix):

> message: Please report this bug to Hang.Si@wias-berlin.de. Include the
> message above, your input data set, and the exact command line you
> used to run this program, thank you.
> description: This failure was caused by a known bug of TetGen.

So I am tempted to think that nobody but the TetGen developers can help you.

Comment: oh,,,I see. Thank you for letting me know that link.